# How to allow user login only once at a time?

Tags: users

1. I want to allow a user login to the site only once at a time. User should not be able to login at other machine/place while he is logged in.
2. I want to user password should get destroyed once used and should promt user to "request new password".
3. I also want to show user login time,logout time, number of visits, last visit time...etc in a block for user.

How can i get these in Drupal?

Answer (score 9):

You can get what you're looking for with a combination of existing modules:

1. [Session limit module](http://drupal.org/project/session_limit)
2. [Password policy module](http://drupal.org/project/password_policy)
3. [User stats module](http://drupal.org/project/user_stats) + [Views module](http://drupal.org/project/views)

You shouldn't have to write a single bit of code using those 3 modules.

You don't mention which version of Drupal you're using but each of those modules have D6 and D7 releases (albeit a dev release for one of them).

Comment: Hi Clive! I got the best solution for all my requirements from you. Thank you very much. But I could not get the logout time/time spent on last login. My main aim is to give access to user for (ex:)1hr. If he logs out after 15minutes, session should be continued from 15mins in the next login till the completion of 1hr and then the password destroy. For this I need logout time. Please suggest me to get this functionality.